# MVC does not accept AddTo Method

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, methods, registration

I am making a simple registration Form. I added the code to save my registrations. I am doing a MVC4 ASP.NET APP , visual studio shows the method Addto as an error. Can you please tell me whats the prb.

Thank you

**Code:**

```
public class RegisterService
{
    public void SaveRegisterDetailts (RegisterViewModel register)
    {
        Table_1 registerDetails = new Table_1();
        registerDetails.UserName = register.UserName;
        registerDetails.Email = register.Email;
        registerDetails.Password = register.Password;

        using (SampleAppEntities dataContext = new SampleAppEntities() )
        {
            dataContext.AddToTable_1(registerDetails);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's smart to first read the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc before asking these questions... It looks to me that this is all new for you and you haven't even searched for the problem because every simple Entity Framework tutorial would give you this answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataContext.Table_1.Add(registerDetails); is the way to write it. So the add method will access the database and then the table and insert the new information.